# how to replace fields from bracket

Tags: c#, .net

```
string MemberId = "1001";
string Password = "123";
string AttendDate = "01/01/2020";

string template = 
  "Dear Member your id is {{id}} and password is {{pwd}} kindly attend on {{date}}";
```

output should be:

```
string template = 
  "Dear Member your id is 1001 and password is 123 kindly attend on 01/01/2020";
```

Comment: Use either string.Replace or Regex.Replace?

Comment: `string actual = template.Replace("{{id}}", MemberId).Replace(...);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a `Dictionary` with the keywords here

```
Dictionary<string, string> keyValues = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    { "{{id}}", "1001" },
    { "{{pwd}}", "123" },
    { "{{date}}", "01/01/2020" }
};
string template = "Dear Member your id is {{id}} and password is {{pwd}} kindly attend on {{date}}";
foreach(var item in keyValues)
{
    template = template.Replace(item.Key, item.Value);
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/6AnRY4

Answer (score 1):

You can use [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated):

```
string template = $"Dear Member your id is {MemberId} and password is {Password} kindly attend on {AttendDate}";
```

Assuming that `template` is being declared as a string literal.

Answer (score 0):

What about this ?

```
    string MemberId = "1001";
    string Password = "123";
    string AttendDate = "01/01/2020";
    string template = string.Format("Dear Member your id is {0} and password is {1} kindly attend on {2}", MemberId, Password, AttendDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

In *general case*, if you can't use *string interpolation* (say if you read `template` from database and then have to do some replacements) you can try *regular expressions*:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

...

private static string MyReplace(string source, IDictionary<string, string> replaces) => 
  Regex.Replace(
    source,
    @"\{\{\p{L}+\}\}",
    m => replaces.TryGetValue(m.Value.Trim('{', '}'), out var v) ? v : "???"
  );
```

Then

```
string template = 
  "Dear Member your id is {{id}} and password is {{pwd}} kindly attend on {{date}}";

Dictionary<string, string> subs = 
  new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) {
    { "id" , "1001"},
    { "pwd", "123" },
    { "date", "01/01/2020"},
     //TODO: add more valid substitutions, if any
     // { "expired", DateTime.Today.AddYears(3).ToString("dd MM yyyy") }
};

template = MyReplace(template, subs);

Console.Write(template);
```

Outcome:

```
Dear Member your id is 1001 and password is 123 kindly attend on 01/01/2020
```